# Getting Error While Installing Angular CLI?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have already Install `node.js` and `npm`.After these two I am running the command `npm install --global @angular/cli` but I am getting an error.

```
C:\Users>npm --v
5.6.0

C:\Users>node --version
v10.2.1

C:\Users>npm install --global @angular/cli
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd: node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng symlink target is not controlled by npm C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-14T05_33_11_503Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Check this:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12016

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in logs. You have to delete the below file:

> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd

This is because you might have other version or some other program is using it and npm is not able to delete as it doesn't have the correct access right for the same.

Just delete the file and try again. (Note: Make sure you are not using it and if doing so then newer version should support the functionalities required)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once and fixed it by doing this, maybe it'll help you.

First open the cmd in Administrator mode ( Windows ) if its Linux    just add sudo before the commands, then type the commands one by one

```
$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think npm has old dependency cache.
try this.

`npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, deleting `ng.cmd` and also `%appdata%\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli` folder solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete **node** Folder under program Files
   C:\Program Files (x86)
2. Delete **npm** and **npm-cache** folders
   C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming
3. Uninstall **Node** if installed from control panel
4. Install stable version of node from official website
   https://nodejs.org/en/
5. verify running below commands
   node -v and npm -v
6. Run npm install -g @angular/cli

Above Steps worked for me..